# I’m unable to get GPO Security Filtering to work for users

Tags: group-policy

I’m unable to get GPO  Security Filtering to work for users (called TestUser) and custom security groups (called TestGroup.)  It does work for Authenticated Users or if I add the Computer.   I did a gpresult on the client computer and confirmed that TestUser lists TestGroup.  I also made sure Read and Apply Group Policy were checked on both TestUser and TestGroup.  I also tried using the builtin Administrators group but no joy.  I’m also running gpupdate (/force) on the server (Windows 2012) and client computer.  I also rebooted the client PC.  I have had this same problem on two different networks so I know it must be some fundamental issue that I don’t understand.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you double check the linking and application of the gpo to the correct OU?

Comment: What does gpresult /h show?

Comment: Thank you Todd, I'm not sure what you mean by application. For troubleshooting purposes I moved the GPO from the OU and into the root container (just under the domain.)  Not sure it matters since it does work if I use Authenticated Users in the filter.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're trying to apply Computer Configuration settings to a user, which will not work. Computer Configuration settings apply to computers, not users. The reason the GPO works when applying it to Authenticated Users is because all computer accounts belong to the Authenticated Users group.

Comment: Thank you Joe,  I think this is exactly what I'm doing.  I started experimenting a few minutes ago with this in mind.  Too bad, I wanted to block IE on certain computers but not block if few select users login to them.  Guess I will have to rethink this one!

Comment: @Greg,  I tried to copy gpresult but it went past the limit allowed by this website.  However, I think joeqwerty figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the *easiest* way (but not the only way) to accomplish what you have described above would be to use loopback processing.

Create a GPO that is linked to the computer's OU and enable loopback processing with the merge option. This is done in the **computer** settings section of the GPO.

In the **user** section of the GPO, use item-level targeting to set up a preference for the group that you want to disable IE for.

Knowing more about your environment might produce a better approach, but this should still get it done.